# how to solve an error:javax.mail does not exist?

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

i copy mail.jar and activation.jar in bin folder of jdk 1.7  but still error javax.mail does not exist

here is my code

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.actiovation.*;
```

Comment: Is this for server side or on Android device?

Comment: is it possible that you give the exact error

Comment: Did you work out you spelt Activation wrong...? `import javax.actiovation.*;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add jar to classpath ([How do I add jar files to the Classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386869/how-do-i-add-jar-files-to-the-classpath)).
 Hope that helps.

Comment: The jar you need can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Comment: @Kushagra Sharma You can solve problem regarding to this posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481269/how-do-i-import-jars-into-my-java-program), but I highly suggest to use any IDE (eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ ...). Any IDE is better than nothing, because you will expire lot of benefits (code completition, debugging, highlighting error, etc).